# Auto Increment SharePoint List Column in Online (o365) using MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-list, flow, auto-increment

I would like to Auto Increment a Column using  MS Flow in SharePoint Online List.

Any instructions on how to do that?

Followed many articles , but that does not use MS Flow, (typically covers using workflow)

Comment: What's the use case? There is no way to add column through Flow for now

Comment: @AkshayRandive Use case is , Already a column exists , I want to increment automatically whenever new item is created in SharePoint List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you have to use Get Item Action of Flow and update the fields

[image]
**UPDATE** you can use the above displayed actions.

Comment: I tried with Custom Action, but the point where i am stuck is  how do i store the variable .  The Logic is to get the ID(values from some other list) and store it in variable , increment to next value and assign the variable to my column.  Can you please point how to do that?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Wonderful, It is working as expected.